# UnsupportedOperationException when compiling a Maven project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Java library that I'm building with Maven and from the command line I can successfully run `mvn test` but when I try to build it or run the tests from IntelliJ, it fails with this error:

```
Information:java: An exception has occurred in the compiler (12.0.2). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
Information:java: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Information:java:   at java.compiler@12.0.2/javax.tools.JavaFileManager.getServiceLoader(JavaFileManager.java:527)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.DelegatingJavaFileManager.getServiceLoader(DelegatingJavaFileManager.java:158)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain$2.invoke(JavacMain.java:290)
Information:java:   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.getServiceLoader(Unknown Source)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.initProcessorLoader(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:266)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:237)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.instance(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:193)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.initProcessAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1136)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:922)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:195)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:460)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:330)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:255)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:213)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1324)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1004)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1071)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:965)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:794)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:376)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:288)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:121)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'projectcommon'
Information:javac 12.0.2 was used to compile java sources
Information:2019-09-28 14:44 - Build completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 1 s 301 ms
Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

Any ideas what's going on?

I've tried refreshing IntelliJ from the Maven project (and it's configured to auto-import).

Both IntelliJ and the command line are using Oracle's JDK 12:

```
> java --version
java 12.0.2 2019-07-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The successful command line run looks like this:

```
> mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< com.example:projectcommon >--------------------
[INFO] Building projectcommon 1.0.0-beta.12
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.17.Final has been relocated to org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.17.Final
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ projectcommon ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\project\code\projectcommon\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ projectcommon ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 38 source files to C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\project\code\projectcommon\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ projectcommon ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\project\code\projectcommon\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ projectcommon ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 16 source files to C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\project\code\projectcommon\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ projectcommon ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\project\code\projectcommon\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.example.projectcommon.crypto.AsymEncryptedDataTest
Tests run: 19, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.391 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.crypto.EncryptedKeyPairTest
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.787 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.crypto.HashedPasswordSpecTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.crypto.HashedPasswordTest
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.677 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.crypto.KeyPairTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.14 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.crypto.PasswordKeySpecTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.crypto.PasswordKeyTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.23 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.crypto.RandomKeyTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.009 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.crypto.SymEncryptedDataTest
Tests run: 32, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.102 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.crypto.VerifierPayloadTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.dto.ErrorDetailTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.dto.ErrorTest
Sep 28, 2019 2:38:03 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.17.Final
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.534 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.models.AccountDtoTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.models.RegistrationDtoTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.139 sec
Running com.example.projectcommon.models.UserDtoTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.06 sec

Results :

Tests run: 94, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.211 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-28T14:38:04+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are affected by [JDK-8228646](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8228646) and [JDK-8223942](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223942) which are fixed in Java 13. I don't see it backported to Java 12 so I guess you should update to newer version.

The root cause is explained in the JDK-8223942 bug description:

> In the module jdk.compiler the in class `com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper` the following calls are not forwarded and lead to calls to interface default which always throws `UnsupportedOperationException`
>
> `ClientCodeWrapper.WrappedJavaFileManager` does not wrap method:
>       `default <S> ServiceLoader<S> getServiceLoader(Location location, Class<S> service) throws IOException`
>
> `ClientCodeWrapper.WrappedStandardJavaFileManager` does not wrap method:
>       `void setLocationForModule(Location location, String moduleName, Collection<? extends Path> paths) throws IOException`
>
> This is true for all versions of JDK, past and present.

Comment: Moving to Java 11 seems to workaround this issue, I'll try Java 13 as soon as there's a scoop package for it. Thank you Karol.